# Why does 写 not have a dot on top?

Tags: etymology, radicals, characters, glyph-origin

Many hanzi have a roof on top, including a dot.  From the HSK2 list, we have:

> 客 家 字 完 室 安 它

The commonly used hanzi 写 is unlike these because it does not have a dot on top.

Chinese-tools.com lists hanzi with the radicals [宀](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r=%E5%AE%80) and [冖](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r=%E5%86%96).  On the list for 冖, the only other one I've seen before with 冖 on top is 农, although I would never had realized.

I'm wondering if there's a reason the hanzi 写, in particular, does not have a dot.

**Question**: Why does 写 not have a dot on top?

(Another exception I can think of is 买, which has the radical 乛 on top, but it has a counterpart 实 with a roof.)

Comment: because they're just two different redicals... 宀 is called 宝盖 and 冖 is called 秃宝盖 (bald 宝盖)

Comment: 写：部首：秃宝盖部，others with 冖 in standard dictionaries (not so many, more than half seem to have low usage frequency) ：冗、军、罕、 冠、冢、冥、冤、幂

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The, new, **Outliers** dictionary provides some insight as to how 寫 became 写:

> **FORM**
>
> 写 is shorthand for 寫. The top part, 冖, is a common abbreviation for 宀. The bottom part is a shorthand abbreviation for 舄 (see the diagram below for how that works).
>
> [image]

which is referenced from:

> 邵源、邵冠勇，2010《簡化漢字解說》，济南：齐鲁书社 2010年12月第一版。

It also continues:

> **COMPONENTS**
>
> 冖
>
> In 写, 冖 is an empty component. It was originally 宀 “building,” a meaning component, hinting at the original meaning “to move something from one location to another.”

The simplified version is just simply old shorthand that was in turn made into a Chinese simplified character.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why, but the traditional form [寫](http://www.zdic.net/z/18/js/5BEB.htm) has the dot. But in the [calligraphy](http://sf.zdic.net/sf/ks/0917/d0b4255ef0441353bc95268d712d59d2.html), there were some styles that don't have the dot before. e.g.

[image]

And one of these styles, i.e. [写](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/5199.htm), is selected as the simplified form.

It is said that in the calligraphy, according to the artistic sence one more stroke or one less stroke is not uncommon.

BTW: There're also some common characters with the radical [冖](http://www.zdic.net/z/jbs/?jbs=%E5%86%96#2), e.g.

> 冗 农 军 罕 冠 冥

Comment: FYI: [颜真卿时代已经有简化字了吗？](https://www.zhihu.com/question/23970496/answer/26259081?utm_medium=social&utm_source=qq)